# Unable to use Drools in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, drools

I understand the latest version of Drools (7.47) descoped the Eclipse Java Compiler (https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.47.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#drools-ecj), but this has broken the integration with Eclipse. I no longer get syntax/error parsing in .drl files, the Rete tree cannot be shown, and the project has a build error:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.ecj.EclipseJavaCompiler cannot be found by org.drools.eclipse_7.47.0.Final`

(This error is the same for the Rete tree and building the project)

Is this a bug in Drools that will be fixed in the next version, or a configuration issue I need to address? If it's a configuration issue, what do I need to do?

Comment: were you able to find fix for this ?

Comment: I managed to email a couple of the Drools devs; they said that maintaining the Eclipse plugin is difficult and so it seems they are not planning to do so anymore. If you go back to plugin version 7.46 and freeze on that version (only the plugin needs to be frozen; the binaries can be newer) it should work again

Comment: thank you for the update, appreciate it. I shall try 7.46 version of plugin and try. What do they recommend we use for authoring rules as developers using Eclipse IDE ? if you happen to know.

Comment: They didn't have a particular recommendation. I have switched to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which has several plugins to support Java. There is also a Drools plugin for Code, but it is not created by the Drools developers, and it only supports syntax highlighting, it doesn't show you errors.

Comment: same here :) have started using that for color. I just wish we had a better editor for drools with all its power at runtimes. thank you for quick update.